# What is the "/dev/xvda1" device?

Tags: mount, virtualization, xen

When I type `mount` on the `root` of my Ubuntu system I get the output

`/dev/xvdal on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)`

I want to know what is the meaning of `/dev/xvdal` in this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are on a Xen VPS(or virtual machine); `xvd*` are simply the Xen disk storage devices (Xen Virtual block Device). They appear instead of sda, etc. when you are using the more efficient paravirtualized Xen disk drivers instead of straight-up SCSI disk emulation. If you list the installed modules (drivers) on a Xen HVM, this driver will show as `blkfront` (or `xen_blk` if you are running on a very old Xen version--pretty rare).

In short, treat `xvda1` exactly as you would `sda1` on a regular PC.

Answer (score 15):

It's probably `/dev/xvda1` rather than `/dev/xvdal`.

Virtual storage devices, representing cloud storage (or paravirtualized storage generally, as [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/166087/22949)), are [typically exposed in Ubuntu through `/dev/xvd` nodes](https://serverfault.com/questions/317652/attached-volumes-do-not-appear-in-dev). `/dev/xvda1` is the first partition of the first such device (just as `/dev/sda1` is the first partition of the first SCSI or SCSI-like storage device).

Comment: Afaik, that nomenclature is exclusive to Xen and does not apply to KVM, Vbox, VMware, etc. The cloud storage association may just be because Amazon EC2s use Xen :)

Comment: @izx You know a hell lot about these machines.

Comment: @darkcrow lol, sadly I have had to know way more than I should about Xen and OpenVZ VPSs.... ;)